# How to implement an efficient excel-like app

Tags: data-structures

I need to implement an efficient excel-like app.
I'm looking for a data structure that will:

- Store the data in an efficient manner (for example - I don't want
  to pre-allocate memory for unused cells).
- Allow efficient update when the user changes a formula in one of the cells

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're looking for an online [dictionary structure](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/dictionary.html). This is a category of structures which allow you to associate one morsel of data (in this case, the coordinates that represent the cell) with another (in this case, the cell contents or formula). The "*online*" adjective means dictionary entries can be added, removed, or changed in real time.

There's many such structures. To name some more common ones: hash tables, binary trees, skip lists, linked lists, and even lists in arrays.

Of course, some of these are more efficient than others (depending on implementation and the number of entries). Typically I use hash tables for this sort of problem.

However, if you need to do range querying "modify all of the cells in this range", you may be better off with a binary tree or a more complicated spatial structure -- but not likely given the simple requirements of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this was my initial idea, but then I got confused thinking about the details..probably because I didn't think of "online" dictionaries. So do you think I should use a hash table which contains another hash table in each of its entries?
For example if the user fills cell number: i-3, am I suppose to add an entry with "i" as key to the first level hash, and then set the value of this entry to be a second level hash object with "3" as key?

Comment: The first morsel of data is the entire 2D cell reference -- I3. You don't need two separate dictionaries or a hierarchy of dictionaries. As long as each cell has a unique identifier (e.g. I3 is a unique identifier), you're good. Say, for example, you store it as row and column allowing rows and columns to be 16 bit integers. Then slam them together to make one 32 bit integer. That integer becomes lookup value for that cell.